# Invalid options in tmux without custom configuration

Tags: macos, zsh, tmux, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I just installed tmux 3.1c on my Mac and have not created any custom configuration(neither ~/.tmux.conf nor ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf exists)

When I run *tmux* in both native Terminal and in iTerm2 I am getting the following errors printed in the top of the screen

```
invalid option: pane-active-border-bg
invalid option: pane-border-bg
```

I am using zsh with oh-my-zsh plugin but have not found anything that could try to set those options.
Are there any ideas on how to fix that issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can search the manual and you search for "`pane-border-style`", so the new way is like this:

```
set -g pane-border-style fg=red
```